# Loki 0.4 - network-manager applet shows disconnected after docker installation

Tags: release-loki, networking

Hi I'm new to elementary os. I had network-manager says my wifi connected perfectly. I installed docker, now network-manager reports wired network disconneted (though wifi is working correctly).
Is there a way to tell network-manager to show only wireless (and not docker useless network interfaces) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been [logged as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-network/+bug/1628541). I'm experiencing a similar issue with Vagrant, which also creates virtual network devices.

Rebooting should fix the problem until you run Docker again, but of course the real solution is for that bug to be fixed.